# How browser understand for using either full standards mode vs almost standard mode?

Tags: html, browser

Quikr Mode I am aware about, However I am wondering we always use DOCTYPE HTMl to tell browser to use standard mode. Hence , whats different ways to tell browser whether it has to use FULL STANDARD MODE or ALMOST STANDARD MODE.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` will set the document to full standard mode. For the doctypes that will trigger almost standard mode check [MDN: "Almost Standards" Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko's_Almost_Standards_Mode) and [Activating Browser Modes with Doctype](https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/). But what is the reason you want to use something else beside `<!DOCTYPE html>`  nowadays?

Comment: Thanks @t.niese for the response ! I just heard about ALMOST Standard mode and wondering what are difference between ALMOST STANDARD MODE and FULL STANDARD MODE and how browser recognize those 2 different mode ?

Comment: You should only care about quirks and almost standard if you need to maintain older websites. There is no reason today to use anything else then  full standard mode (`<!DOCTYPE html>`)